# Class using multiple instance of another class

Tags: c++, class, object, arduino

I want to learn how to use class object within class, especially how to pass an arguments between the objects. I'm trying to create an example object `Calc` which should provide two methods `Calc.sum` and `Calc.sub`. It should use another object `Plus` as a math engine. The `Plus.add` function compile and works well. But I don't know how to initiate multiple instance of `plus` in the `calc`. The code:

```
class Plus{                     // This class works well
    public:
        Plus(int);              // Structure
        int add(int);           // Public method (function)
        int myVar;              // Public property. Just to hold a value.
    private:
        int _init;              // Class-level private variable
};

Plus::Plus(int init){           // Constructor
    _init = init;
}

int Plus::add(int p){           // Method add
    return _init + p;
}

/***************************************************************************/

class Calc{
    public:
        Calc(int);              // Structure
        int sum(int);           // Method sum
        int sub(int);           // Method sub
        int myVar;              // Public property
    private:
        Plus positive(int);     // Class-level private object definition ?
        Plus negative(int);     // This is probably wrong ??
};

Calc::Calc(int init){           // Constructor (also wrong...)
    Plus positive(init);        // Create object "positive" and pass the initial value
    Plus negative(-init);       // Create object "negative" and pass the initial value
}

int Calc::sum(int n){
    return positive.add(n);
}

int Calc::sub(int n){
    return negative.add(n);
}

/***************************************************************************/

Plus two(2);        // Create class object two
Calc five(5);       // Create class object five

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);

    Serial.print("two.add(3) = ");
    Serial.println(two.add(3));         // Calling instance of class Plus
    two.myVar = 100;
    Serial.println(two.myVar);

    Serial.print("five.sum(3) = ");
    Serial.println(five.sum(3));        // Calling instance of class Calc

    Serial.print("five.sub(3) = ");
    Serial.println(five.sub(3));        // Calling instance of class Calc
}

void loop(){}
```

My example is inspired by this article: http://arduinoetcetera.blogspot.cz/2011/01/classes-within-classes-initialiser.html but the code there is for one instance only

1) How to declare multiple instances of `Plus` within `Calc`

2) Is the terminology (comments) right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies here

```
Calc::Calc(int init){           // Constructor (also wrong...)
    Plus positive(init);        // Create object "positive" and pass the initial value
    Plus negative(-init);       // Create object "negative" and pass the initial value
}
```

By doing this, you're creating local variables with the same name as your members: it has no effect.

Should be

```
Calc::Calc(int init): positive(init),negative(-init)
{
}
```

That way you initialize your members even if your members don't have a default constructor.

Oh and that is also wrong in definition of `Calc`

```
    Plus positive(int);     // Class-level private object definition ?
    Plus negative(int);     // This is probably wrong ??
```

replace by

```
    Plus positive;     // Class-level private object definition
    Plus negative;
```

Comment: It does not compile. There must be something else wrong. Sorry, I've spend whole day googling for sollution and I may be tired.

Comment: I found another error by "manual compilation by hand" :), See my edit. Next time please post compilation errors. "it does not compile" is just not enough.